# Unrecognized selector sent to class 0x89e40

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app is crashing with the error: +[AccountService createMockAccountData] unrecognized selector sent to class 0x89e40..Please advise how can I resolve this error? I'm new to Objective C. Here's my code:

```
@interface AccountService : NSObject
+ (NSMutableArray *)accounts: createMockAccountData;
@end


#import AccountService.h"
@implementation AccountService
+(NSMutableArray *)accounts: createMockAccountData{
    NSMutableArray * accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UserAccount *mockUserAccount1 = [[UserAccount alloc] init];
    *mockUserAccount1 setName:@"Stella"];
    [accounts addObject:mockUserAccount1];
    UserAccount *mockUserAccount2  = [[UserAccount alloc] init];
    [mockUserAccount2 setName:@"Marko"];
    [accounts addObject:mockUserAccount2];
    [mockUserAccount1 release];
    [mockUserAccount2 release];
    return accounts;
}
```

....

In my controller...I'm invoking this class method like this:

```
NSMutableArray *accounts = [AccountService createMockAccountData];
NSUInteger count = [accounts count];
NSLog(@"# of records = %d",count);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
+(NSMutableArray *)accounts: createMockAccountData{
```

to

```
+(NSMutableArray *)createMockAccountData{
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is messed up. Method headers look like this:

```
 - (return type)name:(parameter type)parameterName
```

Comment: Also, the `+` indicates a class-level method, whereas `-` indicates instance-level method